# Difference Between two dates postgresql In Excel Format

Tags: postgresql, csv

Hello I want To Show SQL difference between two dates: 
*** END DATE = dt_termino / now() 

* START DATE = dt_inicio**

I have a Function to write in CSV... but in my csv ouput like:

```
id_task_tarefa |      dt_inicio      |     dt_termino      |     sum
211            | 2016-01-25 10:40:25 | 2016-01-27 08:51:02 | 01 22:10:37
210            | 2016-01-25 10:40:29 | 2016-01-27 08:50:21 | 01 22:09:52
```

I need a format to output in Excel [h]:mm:ss;@
like this

```
id_task_tarefa |      dt_inicio      |     dt_termino      |    sum
211            | 2016-01-25 10:40:25 | 2016-01-27 08:51:02 | 46:10:37
210            | 2016-01-25 10:40:29 | 2016-01-27 08:50:21 | 46:09:52
```

Here's My SQL:

```
SELECT id_task_tarefa, 
       dt_inicio, 
       dt_termino, 
       to_char(COALESCE(dt_termino::timestamp, now()::timestamp) 
             - dt_inicio::timestamp,'DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM crm.task_interacao
```

Comment: Consider that `extract(epoch from timestamp1 - timestamp2)` returns the number of second between two timestamps. Then you can use simple formulas to convert it to hours, minutes and seconds: `x::int / (60*60) as h, x::int % (60*60) / 60 as m, x::int % 60 as s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function may be convenient for you:

```
create or replace function interval_in_hours(interval)
returns text language sql as $$
    select format('%s:%s',
        (extract (epoch from $1) / 3600)::int,
        to_char($1, 'mi:ss'))
$$;
```

Use:

```
with the_data (id_task_tarefa, dt_inicio, dt_termino) as (
    values
        (211, timestamp '2016-01-25 10:40:25', timestamp '2016-01-27 08:51:02'),
        (210, timestamp '2016-01-25 10:40:29', timestamp '2016-01-27 08:50:21') 
    )

select *, interval_in_hours(dt_termino- dt_inicio)::interval as sum
from the_data;

 id_task_tarefa |      dt_inicio      |     dt_termino      |   sum    
----------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
            211 | 2016-01-25 10:40:25 | 2016-01-27 08:51:02 | 46:10:37
            210 | 2016-01-25 10:40:29 | 2016-01-27 08:50:21 | 46:09:52
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I wonder why you return text instead of returning interval? And now I see interval show the correct format, Wouldnt convert the diferent to interval solve it  easy?

Comment: The function returns text in analogy to `to_char()`, `format()`, etc. There is no problem to change it to interval. In the example I have casted the result to interval to make sure the format is proper, but it is unecessary of course (I could leave text without any visual difference).

Comment: Thew weird part is `'46:09:52'::interval` return `46:09:52` and not `01 22:10:37` In that case maybe there is a way to covert the `(timestamp - timestamp)::interval` direct to the format we want.

Comment: There is nothing strange, `interval '20:00:00'+ interval '20:00:00'` gives `'40:00:00'`. There is the function `justify_hours()` to get `'1 day 16:00:00'` instead. As far as I know there is no a (standard) reverse function.

Comment: How dont you find strange `+` produce `40:00:00` but `-` produce `01 22:10:37` ??

Comment: I just make a question, maybe someone know  ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107999/why-postgres-show-two-different-format-for-same-interval-value

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is a better way but works

```
SELECT '2016-01-25 10:40:25' start_date, 
       '2016-01-27 08:51:02' end_date, 
       to_char('2016-01-27 08:51:02'::timestamp 
             - '2016-01-25 10:40:25'::timestamp,'HH24:MI:SS') as sum_text,
       TRUNC(EXTRACT(epoch FROM '2016-01-27 08:51:02'::timestamp - '2016-01-25 10:40:25'::timestamp)/3600)  time_diff,
       TRUNC(EXTRACT(epoch FROM '2016-01-27 08:51:02'::timestamp - '2016-01-25 10:40:25'::timestamp)/3600)  || ':' ||
       to_char('2016-01-27 08:51:02'::timestamp 
             - '2016-01-25 10:40:25'::timestamp,'MI:SS') result
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]